# Measure application stats with chrome dev tool?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, google-chrome-devtools

I am using dev tool(mainly network tab ) provided by chrome . I know it provides a lot of stats [Chrome Dev tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#timing-explanation) but  I need to measure below stats

**1. Time taken by webserver  to process the web request ?**

I know there chrome provides `Waiting(TTFB)` but that is Time To First Byte which means  the time the server took to prepare the response and time taken by data to travel from server to browser

**2. Time taken by data to transfer from server to browser ?**

I see `Content Download` stats . Is it the network travel time ? If yes Is it

```
 `Time taken by webserver  to process the web request  = TTFB - Content Download`
```

**3. Time taken by browser to render data ?**

Also in below image I see three stats Finish, DOMContentLoaded, Load  ?

[image]

Mine understanding is

**Finish :-** Complete time taken by request from start to finish

**DOMContentLoaded :-** Time tiken by request to the point when DOMContentLoaded is done(i.e. HTML is rendered alongwith JS/CS files downloaded)

**Load :-** Time tiken by request to the point when onLoad event is fired